# Native queries in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb, simple-framework

Is there a way to handle native queries in JAXB and or SimpleXML? I'm looking for something similar to [JPA Named Queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named).

In our environment we want to have the same query API for JAXB, SimpleXML and JPA.

I am aware that there is

```
jaxbContext.getValueByXPath(customer, "@id", null, Integer.class);
```

but I would need to get multiple objects wich have an attribute with a certain value.

It would be best to archieve something like this in JPA/SimpleXML:

```
@NamedQuery(name="orderFromCountry", query="SELECT o FROM Order o where o.address like :address")
```

Answer (score 1):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) does not currently define any sort of query API like JPA does.  The `getValueByXPath` you included in your question is an extension offered by [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php). Below is an example of its use (I'm the MOXy lead):

- [EclipseLink Moxy unmarshall and getValueByXPath gives null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687460/eclipselink-moxy-unmarshall-and-getvaluebyxpath-gives-null)

Since JAXB objects are just POJOs you could use any sort of query implementation with them.  Below is a link to a related question that may help out:

- [How do you query object collections in Java (Criteria/SQL-like)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93417/how-do-you-query-object-collections-in-java-criteria-sql-like)