# Moxy's getValueByXPath returns null for all but root element

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, moxy

[See my sscce](https://github.com/djeikyb/moxy-xpath-sscce).

Looking at examples, it looks like I should be able to use moxy's [getValueByXPath](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/JAXBContext.html#getValueByXPath(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.NamespaceResolver,%20java.lang.Class)) to access a child element of an umarshalled xml object. But instead I'm always returned null. Attributes on the root object are accessible.

When I run the example in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17700827/659715), it works fine :/ Here's what I'm doing:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" AltLangID="alt lang id fnord">
   <Inventories AreaID="areaID_fnord">
      <Inventory>
         <UniqueID ID="inventory unique id fnord"/>
      </Inventory>
   </Inventories>
</OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQ>
```

java:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

....

OTAHotelInvCountNotifRQ rq = ...
JAXBContext ctx = (JAXBContext) JAXBContextFactory.createContext("org.opentravel.ota._2003._05", Main.class.getClassLoader());
String altLangId = ctx.getValueByXPath(rq, "@AltLangID", null, String.class);
assertThat("rq's altlang attr", altLangId, is(ALT_LANG_ID));

InvCountType inventories = ctx.getValueByXPath(rq, "Inventories", null, InvCountType.class);
assertThat("inventories", inventories, is(not(nullValue())));
```

I have a runnable [simple self-contained complete example](https://github.com/djeikyb/moxy-xpath-sscce) (`mvn exec:java`). I'm not able to change the OTA classes (I generated them from xsd and included them for convenience).

Any ideas why this is returning null instead of the expected object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your XML document is namespace qualified, you need to to namespace qualify your XPath.  Then you need to provide the prefix to namespace mapping pairings using an instance of `NamespaceResolver`.  This is passed as a parameter to the `getValueByXPath` method.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBHelper;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.NamespaceResolver;
import org.opentravel.ota._2003._05.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.opentravel.ota._2003._05", ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader(), null);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        OTAHotelInvCountNotifRQ rq = (OTAHotelInvCountNotifRQ) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        NamespaceResolver nsResolver = new NamespaceResolver();
        nsResolver.put("ns", "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05");

        InvCountType inventories = JAXBHelper.getJAXBContext(jc).getValueByXPath(rq, "ns:Inventories", nsResolver, InvCountType.class);
        System.out.println(inventories);
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to read more about xml namespaces though, because I don't understand conceptually why this is necessary. But thanks so much for helping with my immediate practical problem! Off to read the w3c xml name spec doc..

Comment: Just realised it's totally fine to map an empty string as the prefix. It's nice not having to prefix every element in every xpath expression when there's only the one namespace.